# Create iPhone app now with plans to support iPad later

Tags: ios

I would like to create an iPhone app for now and get it released with plans to make an iPad app later.  I don't want to charge people twice to get both versions.  Do I create a universal app now and delete the iPad storyboard or do I create an iPhone app now and add an iPad storyboard later(if that is even possible)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make it a universal app, then it will be available for both iPhone and iPad. So you should definitely not publish a universal app now it you want to support the iPad only later.

Later, it is easy to change the type of the app to universal, and make the appropriate changes in your code to add support for the iPad.